# Is there a way to have one SQL query using ActiveRecord instead of two when calling an association on an association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, rails-activerecord

Assume we have users, posts, and comments. Users have many posts, posts have many comments and belong to a user. Comments only belong to posts.

Assume I have a comment, and I want to get the user associated to the post.

I could do: `comment.post.user`.

What this does is fire off 2 SQL queries (unless the post is already cached):

```
Post Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts"  WHERE "posts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
```

Now, I'm not asking if it is possible to make one SQL query for this. I know it is. Is there a way through ActiveRecord to have only one query be made?

I suppose it may not even be a big deal if the above is done in a transaction, but I doubt it is.

Comment: Yes, they are called joins. http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/  After you review this try out some SQL if you still struggle, post back table structure and what you've tried and we'll help!

Comment: I know. I said that I know it is possible to make one SQL query, that way being joins, but is there a nice way with ActiveRecord to do that in the case I showed above.

Comment: Missed that part  I'd edit the subject to include Active record and drop the  SQL tag then.  This is more of an activeRecord question than SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .includes method: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-includes